# How to show specific link to user that's signed in and on specific page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code for part of my navigation:

```
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_profile_path(current_user.profile) %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Edit Account', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
  <% elsif user_signed_in? and params[:controller] == 'profiles#edit' %>
    <li><%= link_to 'View Profile', profile_path(current_user.profile) %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Edit Account', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
  <% else %>
    <li><%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %></li>
  <% end %>
```

I want different links to show depending on where the "user_signed_in" is. However, my `<% elsif user_signed_in? and params[:controller] == 'profiles#edit' %>` doesn't seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`profiles` is your controller, and `edit` is your action, so you need to specify them as separate things:

```
elsif user_signed_in? && params[:controller] == 'profiles' && params[:action] == 'edit'
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides what others already mentioned, as this code is written, when `user_signed_in?` is `true` you will **always** fall into the first block and **never** hit `elsif` block.
You would have to fix condition that deals with controller and action **AND** make this a first condition so that your code will execute as intended.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. I'm sure you saved me a couple minutes of confusion.

Comment: Good catch, I completely overlooked that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `params[:controller]`, but it only contains the name of the controller. `params[:action]` will contain the action-name.

Even cleaner is to use `controller_name` and `action_name` which are also available.

Like so:

```
<% elsif user_signed_in? and controller_name == 'profiles' and action_name == 'edit' %>
```

#### Tip for the future

You pose this question, but in fact it is extremely easy to show what `params[:controller]` contains, just do something like

```
 <%= "Controller name = #{params[:controller]}" %>
```

somewhere in your view. Temporary of course :) But then you would immediately know why your condition does not work.

HTH.

Comment: Technically, what's the difference between params[:controller] and controller_name? Is one a better practice over the other?

Comment: I personally like `controller_name` better, but that is personal opinion. In ruby/rails there are many ways to achieve the same goal, choose the one you like the best.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for taking the time to answer and explain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the "url" for showing links or hiding it , you can use :

```
 if request.path == "/profiles/edit"
```

or the url you'd like . As you can guess , the path's format accepts wildcards too : /profiles/*